# ViewState doesn't remember value from previous page init

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, failed-to-load-viewstate, loadviewstate

What am I doing wrong here. I can't get ViewState to work:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Method1();
}

private void Method1()
{
    Element.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
}
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ViewState["x"] != null) 
               // use ViewState["x"] from previous Page Init
    //do processing ...

    //in the end, store value for future use
    ViewState["x"] = myLabel.Text;
}
```

I am reloading the page, so first the Page Init is triggered, where I do changes, before these changes I read from ViewState previous value of a variable, then I do processing, then override that value for subsequent use (in my next Page Init), after which I override it again.

Problem is my ViewState is null , it doesn't store/remember the value I gave it at the previous page init
Thank you

Comment: if your problem is resolve by the below answer ,then mark that acceptable for other users

Comment: Did I resolve your question? Please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as `ViewState` is page specific and is actually stored in the HTML of the rendered page.  You will need to pass the value via a `POST` or in the query string or store it in a session or you could cache the value in the asp.net cache which you will be able to access on the other page.

You can use `ViewState` to transfer data to the same page on Postback.

For setting `ViewState`:

`ViewState["FirstName"] = "SuperMan";`

For retrieving `ViewState` on postback:

`string sFirstName = ViewState["FirstName"].ToString();`

You can use the Context to Transfer data to the one page to another.

**Page1.aspx.cs**

`this.Context.Items["FirstName"] = "SuperMan";`

**Page2.aspx.cs**

`string sFirstName = this.Context.Items["FirstName"].ToString();`

You can use the `Session` variable to preserve the common data which is required almost for every page or across the application for the specific user.

For setting `Session`:

`Session["FirstName"] = "SuperMan";`

Applied to your code:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["x"] != null)
    { 
        // do processing

        // in the end, store value for future use
        Session["x"] = myLabel.Text;
    }
}
```

For retrieving `Session` from any page till the session is valid:

`string sFirstName = Session["FirstName"].ToString();`

Same way you can use `Cookies` also, but cookies will be stored on the client.

Comment: Gotnull, how should I pass the value at button click?

Comment: Use `Session["x"]` instead of `ViewState["x"]`.

Answer (score 0):

ViewState just remember value on its page and can't pass value to another page , for use another session state , like Session variable , query string etc

simple use session variable like this

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["x"] != null) 
               // use Session["x"] from previous Page Init
    //do processing ...

    //in the end, store value for future use
    Session["x"] = myLabel.Text;
}
```

Comment: save data in session like this  Session["x"] = myLabel.Text; and use any where in project